# How to run one qt application from another qt application

Tags: qt, qt4, qprocess

I have one Qt application (App1).
I want to run App1 from another qt application (App2).
I have tried using QProcess but App1 doesnt run.
Kindly help me out.
I am working on RHEL 6.

```
     QProcess process = new QProcess();
    QString program = "/home/user1/Desktop/MyApp/App1";
    process->start(program);
```

Comment: Have you checked what error codes are returned?

Comment: i am not getting any error in code but my App1 doesn't run.

Comment: From comments below Luca Carlon answer I assume that your "App1" is problem here. Could you show us some code from App1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute(program);
qDebug("Exit code is: %d.", exitCode);
```

and check what happens. This is a sync call. After you understand what is happening, change it back to async if you need it.

Comment: With this code, App1 execution begings but i am getting error as
ERROR!! could not open : App1.ui
Exit code is: 1.

Although App1.ui is present in same folder

Comment: Then check the ExitStatus and ProcessError using QProcess so that you can collect more information.

Comment: working fine now..Thanks 

Is it possible to show the newly executed application inside my current class QWidget?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QProcess *p= new QProcess(this);
p->start("yourotherapp.exe",QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```